# How to run shell script for ratchet on browser while talnet on cmd working fine

Tags: php, ratchet

Telnet localhost 8080 is working fine but after that when i create shell script on localhost then it shows error in firefox and chrome see below

`Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:8080/.
var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');`

and here is my shell script

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
   </script>
   <script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
    conn.onopen = function(e) {
     console.log("Connection established!");
    };

   conn.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e.data);
     };
     });
   </script>
```

and here is my chat-server.php code
    '

```
   require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

   $server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new Chat()
        )
    ),
    8080
    );

   $server->run();'
```

shell script is saved in info.php in root directory and chat-server.php saved in root/bin/ directory but always shows same error,i don't know how to run ratchet shell script on localhost.please help!

Comment: Have you tested with any other websocket client? I think it would help us if you posted your server code.

Comment: no i did not use other,but i have to use this one and i have updated my question.thanks for quick reply,now please check it and give me some suggestion.

Comment: It all looks fine to me. Any chance firefox is using a proxy?

Comment: @Raj Did you start the server from the cmd terminal and kept it running? Like going to command prompt and into your project directory and runnin `php bin/chat-server.php`

Answer (score 0):

Man I struggled with this for hours today and I hope this helps someone.

My server Setup:  Apache/2.4.18 on Ubuntu 14.04.

```
var conn = new WebSocket('ws://xxx.xxxx.xxx:8888');
```

Error:

> failed: WebSocket opening handshake timed out.

I ended up not having the port configured correctly and needed to run:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8888 -j ACCEPT
```